# Can it work together head, sed and regex into one bash script?

Tags: regex, bash, sed, head

I have *MyInitialTextFile.txt* with these characteristics: `<p><nsup></nsup> <b>Abc 1:2<sup>varied text`.

- every line starts with this: `<p><nsup></nsup> <b>`
- it is followed by an expression like this: Abc 1:2 or by 2Ab 1:2
- always followed by: `<sup>`
- followed by varied text afterwards.

`<p><nsup></nsup> <b>`Abc 1:2`<sup>`varied text

`<p><nsup></nsup> <b>`Abc 1:2`<sup>`varied text

`<p><nsup></nsup> <b>`Abc 1:3`<sup>`varied text

`<p><nsup></nsup> <b>`Abc 1:4`<sup>`varied text

`<p><nsup></nsup> <b>`Abc 1:4`<sup>`varied text

`<p><nsup></nsup> <b>`Abc 1:4`<sup>`varied text

I need to:

1. Select the first line(s) from *MyInitialTextFile.txt* if they start the same. In my case the first two lines. And then transfer these two lines into a *TransitionalTextFile.txt*
   For this I used head in bash:

```
head -n 2 MyInitialTextFile.txt > TransitionalTextFile.txt
```

2. Where I would apply on them manually a sequence of two regex expressions.
   For regex I used:

Find1: (\n)  #that is, find Line Feed (an enter on keyboard)

Replace1: "    "  #that is, Replace with 5 empty spaces

Find2: (.*)  #that is, select the entire string

Replace2:  $1\n  #that is, Replace with all selected (the entire string), and add a Line Feed at the end.

3. Transfer the content of *TransitionalTextFile.txt* to the end of a new text file with the same name as found in first string Abc 1:2.
   For this I used:

   `head -n 1 TransitionalTextFile.txt >> 'Abc 1:2.txt'`

This will be always *-n 1* because following the regex step, all the text becomes one entry, even if there were two strings selected initially.

4. Delete from *MyInitialTextFile.txt* the number of lines that I transferred, which for me there were two lines.
   For this I used sed in bash:

   `sed -i '1,2d' MyInitialTextFile.txt`

And the process continues with the next one line:
`<p><nsup></nsup> <b>`Abc 1:3`<sup>`varied text

I made all the above four steps work manually, but my problem is how to bring all these four steps into one script. That is, to select the strings from a initial file and transfer them to another file via regex where I delete the line feed between them and I add a line feed at the end of them so that it will look like this:

`<p><nsup></nsup> <b>`Abc 1:2`<sup>`varied text `<p><nsup></nsup> <b>`Abc 1:2`<sup>`varied text

At the end I have to delete from my initial file these two strings.
**I would appreciate any help to bring these four steps into one script.**
Thank you.

Comment: `Find2: (.*)

Replace2: $1\n` What does that mean or represent? What is `$1`? You want to replace newlines with 5 spaces and add a trailing newline?

Comment: You lost me at the second bullet. Please, be more descriptive and show the expected output, even between bullets, if you have to.

Comment: Could you explain also what you want to do? You want to extract lines form a txt file that have the same `Abc <this number>:<and this number>` and group them and write them to separate files? Your steps are unclear - could you post one code block of what is happening, with descriptions in `# comments` in the code? Are you asking XY question - you have some job, you solved it with some commands, now you ask how to combine these commands. Aren't you interested in how to solve that particular job instead, or are you specifically asking purely how to combine commands?

Comment: You lost me at `Find1: (\n)` :-)

Comment: I'd suggest to update the description of the problem by dropping examples of expressions or putting them only as an example of a well described step. Describe your input, and put some more effort on the expected output description, maybe some examples of output files. This should help a lot with understanding the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this (taking one for the team :)? Using awk (**Notice:** it creates files like `Abc 1:2` or whatever is between `<b>` and `<sup>`):

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    FS="<sup>"                 # split at this delimiter
}
{
    if($1==p) {                # if first part equals first part of previous split
        b=b "     " $0         # append to the output buffer
    }
    else {                     # if first part differs, do stuff
        if(NR>1) {             # first line needs not printing
            print b >> t[n]
            # close t[n]       # uncomment if if needed
        }
        n=split($1,t,/<b>/)    # get the changing part
        b=$0                   # reset buffer
    }
    p=$1                       # create previous to compare on next round
}
END {
    print b >> t[n]            # flush the rest of the buffer
}' file
```

Output of `cat Abc\ 1\:2`:

```
<p><nsup></nsup> <b>Abc 1:2<sup>varied text     <p><nsup></nsup> <b>Abc 1:2<sup>varied text
```

Depending on the awk flavor used, if you start running out of file descriptors, add a `close(t[n])` after the `print >>`s.

Comment: Yes, like this indeed. I do not mind to take one for the team:) Thank you. Only that every line has to be appended to (added at the end of) a preexisting file with the name _Abc 1:2_, _Abc 1:3_, etc.

Comment: Now it should append, untested, though.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to implement `head` in `sed` so it's usually not necessary to combine the two. However, your problem seems more suitable for Awk, which is both easier to read and to write than the rather cryptic and terse low-level language of `sed`.

Guessing somewhat as to what your expected output should look like, try this.

```sh
awk '/^<p><nsup><\/nsup> <b>/ {
    str = substr($0, 21); split(str, n, /<sup>/);
    if (n[1] != id) {
        if (d) { printf "\n" >d; close (d) }
        d = n[1] ".txt"
        id = n[1]
        sep = ""
    }
    printf "%s%s", sep, $0 >d
    sep = "     "
    }
END { if (d) printf "\n" >d }' MyInitialTextFile.txt
```

This extracts the string between `<b>` and `<sup>` and writes each line to a file named by that string, replacing newlines with five spaces.

Demo: https://ideone.com/79P4tk